# Unknown hadoop job associated with action. Failing this action

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I'm trying to run mapreduce program from OOzie. But getting below error

`JA017: Unknown hadoop job [job_local100982864_0001] associated with action [0000000-191002180059803-oozie-hdus-W@RunMapreduceJob].  Failing this action`!

Here is `workflow.xml`

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="simple-Workflow">
   <start to="RunMapreduceJob" />
   <action name="RunMapreduceJob">
      <map-reduce>
         <job-tracker>localhost:8088</job-tracker>
         <name-node>hdfs://localhost:9000</name-node>
         <prepare>
            <delete path="hdfs://localhost:9000/dataoutput"/>
         </prepare>
         <configuration>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
               <value>default</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
               <value>MovieReviewsHadoop.DataDividerByUser.DataDividerMapper</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
               <value>MovieReviewsHadoop.DataDividerByUser.DataDividerReducer</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.output.key.class</name>
               <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.output.value.class</name>
               <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
               <value>/data</value>
            </property>
            <property>
               <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
               <value>/dataoutput</value>
            </property>
         </configuration>
      </map-reduce>
      <ok to="end" />
      <error to="fail" />
   </action>
   <kill name="fail">
      <message>Mapreduce program Failed</message>
   </kill>
   <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

Map reduce Program

```
package MovieReviewsHadoop;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

import java.io.IOException;

public class DataDividerByUser {
    public static class DataDividerMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

        // MAP_Method:divide data by user

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            //input user,movie,rating
            String[] user_movie_rating = value.toString().trim().split(","); // we have 3 list here 
            int userID = Integer.parseInt(user_movie_rating[0]);
            String movieID = user_movie_rating[1];
            String rating_score = user_movie_rating[2];

            context.write(new IntWritable(userID), new Text(movieID + ':' + rating_score));

        }
    }

    public static class DataDividerReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

        // reduce method

        @Override
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            //merge data for one user
            StringBuilder strblder = new StringBuilder();
            while (values.iterator().hasNext()){
                strblder.append("," + values.iterator().next());
            }

            // key-value pair: key = userID value = movie1: rating_score, movie2: rating_score.....
            context.write(key, new Text(strblder.toString().replaceFirst(",", "")));

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Movie");
        job.setMapperClass(DataDividerMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(DataDividerReducer.class);

        job.setJarByClass(DataDividerByUser.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        TextInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }

}
```

I'm sure, I'm doing something wrong in my workflow.xml. But dont know what's that.

Can anyone suggest what am doing wrong ? Because manual run is running fine.

1) Am I giving my Mapper classes correctly in xml ..?

2) Am I giving my Reducer classes correctly in xml ..?

3) Am I giving delepath correct in xml .. ?

Here is my `job.properties` file too.

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:9000
jobTracker=localhost:8088
queueName=default
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/Config
```

Update: Log

```
2019-10-08 16:49:26,519  INFO ActionStartXCommand:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@:start:] Start action [0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2019-10-08 16:49:26,520  INFO ActionStartXCommand:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@:start:] [***0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2019-10-08 16:49:26,520  INFO ActionStartXCommand:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@:start:] [***0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2019-10-08 16:49:26,625  INFO ActionStartXCommand:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node] Start action [0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2019-10-08 16:49:27,201  WARN MapReduceActionExecutor:544 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node] Exception in check(). Message[JA017: Unknown hadoop job [job_local1373301427_0005] associated with action [0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node].  Failing this action!]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA017: Unknown hadoop job [job_local1373301427_0005] associated with action [0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node].  Failing this action!
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.check(JavaActionExecutor.java:1201)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1136)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:228)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:63)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:281)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:323)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:252)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:174)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-10-08 16:49:27,201  WARN ActionStartXCommand:544 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node] Error starting action [mr-node]. ErrorType [FAILED], ErrorCode [JA017], Message [JA017: Unknown hadoop job [job_local1373301427_0005] associated with action [0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node].  Failing this action!]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA017: Unknown hadoop job [job_local1373301427_0005] associated with action [0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node].  Failing this action!
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.check(JavaActionExecutor.java:1201)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1136)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:228)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:63)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:281)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:323)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:252)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:174)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-10-08 16:49:27,202  WARN ActionStartXCommand:544 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node] Failing Job due to failed action [mr-node]
2019-10-08 16:49:27,203  WARN LiteWorkflowInstance:544 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node] Workflow Failed. Failing node [mr-node]
2019-10-08 16:49:27,276  INFO KillXCommand:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[-] STARTED WorkflowKillXCommand for jobId=0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W
2019-10-08 16:49:27,312  INFO KillXCommand:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[-] ENDED WorkflowKillXCommand for jobId=0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W
2019-10-08 16:49:27,613  INFO CallbackServlet:541 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node] callback for action [0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node]
2019-10-08 16:49:27,619 ERROR CompletedActionXCommand:538 - SERVER[localhost] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[-] JOB[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node] XException, 
org.apache.oozie.command.CommandException: E0800: Action it is not running its in [FAILED] state, action [0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node]
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.CompletedActionXCommand.eagerVerifyPrecondition(CompletedActionXCommand.java:77)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:251)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:174)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

09 Oct 2019

I've taken worflow.xml sample from Oozie's sample worklfow which comes under oozie's installation and used same folder structure in HDFS too.

Please below updates.

Updated `workflow.xml`

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="map-reduce-wf">
    <start to="mr-node"/>
    <action name="mr-node">
        <map-reduce>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/${outputDir}"/>
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
                    <value>MovieReviewsHadoop.DataDividerByUser$DataDividerMapper</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
                    <value>MovieReviewsHadoop.DataDividerByUser$DataDividerReducer</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
                    <value>1</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                    <value>/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/input-data/text</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                    <value>/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/${outputDir}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Map/Reduce failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:9000
jobTracker=localhost:8088
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples
user.name=hduser
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/map-reduce
outputDir=map-reduce
```

Folder structure

```
https://prnt.sc/pgq4ea
```

Action Configuration in OOzie after run ..!

```
<map-reduce xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
  <job-tracker>localhost:8088</job-tracker>
  <name-node>hdfs://localhost:9000</name-node>
  <prepare>
    <delete path="hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/examples/output-data/map-reduce" />
  </prepare>
  <configuration>
    <property>
      <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
      <value>default</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
      <value>MovieReviewsHadoop.DataDividerByUser$DataDividerMapper</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
      <value>MovieReviewsHadoop.DataDividerByUser$DataDividerReducer</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
      <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
      <value>/user/hduser/examples/input-data/text</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
      <value>/user/hduser/examples/output-data/map-reduce</value>
    </property>
  </configuration>
</map-reduce>
```

Comment: When you run an oozie info command on the workflow, does it give you a job id? or does the map reduce action never even start?

Comment: @grantler, Ues it gives jobID..! 0000002-191002221246320-oozie-hdus-W my job ID mentioned in error too..! It creates Ouput folder too..but never produces the output file. All sucessful happens when I ran manually using mapreduce Jar.

Comment: @grantler, It says..Unknown hadoop job..What does it means ..?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the reason (I will keep my previous answer undeleted though, until you clarify my question below it):

Since you have created your mapper and reducer classes as static classes inside a single class `DataDividerByUser`, you need to specify them in the workflow as:

```
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.class</name>
        <value>MovieReviewsHadoop.DataDividerByUser$DataDividerMapper</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.class</name>
        <value>MovieReviewsHadoop.DataDividerByUser$DataDividerReducer</value>
    </property>
```

In other words you need to replace `.` with `$` between the base class and mapper/reducer class

Comment: Update the log after making changes you had suggested.

Comment: it was `[0000000-191002180059803-oozie-hdus-W@RunMapreduceJob]` before, now it is `[0000005-191006102551747-oozie-hdus-W@mr-node]`. the action name changed to `mr-node`, did you change it yourself or you run another workflow?

Comment: and the app name was `simple-Workflow`, now it is `map-reduce-wf`, re-check the workflow that you're running